# How to pass the dynamic exposed port in container to my application?

Tags: scala, docker, akka, travis-ci

I have this configuration for database in my akka project:

```
mydb = {
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/play_db?useSSL=false"
  username = "root"
  password = ""
}
```

I'm trying to build mysql in a container by using docker-compose. 
However, I need the port to be dynamic instead of always 3306
After running "docker-compose up" how can I pass this exposed port to my AKKA app?.

Exists any standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is next:

1. If you not care get the port of mysql, by pass next & go step 2.

   Otherwise, define db container's name in `docker-compose.yml`, e.g. db_container; then after `docker-compose up`, you could use:

   `docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "80/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' db_container`

   to get the dynamic changed host port which map for container's 3306 port.
2. Let's suppose the port you dynamic get is `32768`, then in the shell, which you launch your akka project, do next:

   ```
   export MYSQL_PORT=32768
   ```

   Modify `application.conf` of your akka project as next:

   ```
   jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:"${MYSQL_PORT}"/play_db?useSSL=false"
   ```

   Then, when akka project starts, it will get the port from environment variable `MYSQL_PORT`.